# Waiting for mongodb in docker-compose does not work

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I'm using docker-compose, nodejs, mongodb.

When I run `docker-compose up`, nodejs is running before mongo is fully running, which is causing the problem.

I wrote the following `Dockerfile` and `docker-compose.yml`.

### Dockerfile

```
FROM node:12

RUN mkdir /usr/app
WORKDIR /usr/app

COPY . /usr/app

RUN npm install

EXPOSE 8000

## Add the wait script to the image
ADD https://github.com/ufoscout/docker-compose-wait/releases/download/2.8.0/wait /wait
RUN chmod +x /wait

CMD /wait && npm run prod
```

### docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"

services:
  node:
    container_name: node
    links:
      - mongo
    depends_on:
      - mongo
    env_file: .env
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "80:8000"
    restart: unless-stopped
  mongo:
    container_name: mongo
    image: mongo:4.0-xenial
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - mongodb:/data/db
volumes:
  mongodb:
```

Also I wick docker-compose-wait telling me the following echo:

### Echo In docker-compose-wait

```
node     | [INFO  wait] Host mongo:27017 is now available!
node     | [INFO  wait] --------------------------------------------------------
node     | [INFO  wait] docker-compose-wait - Everything's fine, the application can now start!
node     | [INFO  wait] --------------------------------------------------------
```

And afterwards nodejs runs, but eventually it returns disconnected.

This problem only appears when mongodb is `localhost`.

When I enter the DB URL of the cloud that is running normally, it works normally.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `This problem only appears when mongodb is localhost.` what does it mean?

Comment: @NobbyNobbs I have specified the url where mongo db is running as mongodb://localhost:27017/db. In this case, problems arise.

Comment: Use `mongo:27017`. Localhost inside the container it's container itself.

Comment: @NobbyNobbs The Mongo DB URL I mentioned is the URL that will be used for the DB connection of the actual application. Should I use mongo:27017 in the URL of the application where the real server is running?

Comment: No, you should use suitable connection string for each particular case. In case of docker-compose you have two docker containers - your application and `mongo`, so your app will connecting to database with `mongo:27017`. You could set connection strint through environment variables, as recommended in famous [12 factor app](https://12factor.net/).

Answer (score 0):

As [NobbyNobbs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66843822/waiting-for-mongodb-in-docker-compose-does-not-work#comment118157012_66843822) mentioned in comments, you should use service name or container name instead of `localhost` to connect to your `mongodb` container.

In your case, `localhost:27017` in `node` container means `node:27017`. So as `mongodb` is not running inside of `node` container and port `27017` is not allocated to any service in `node` container, then you'll get error.

You should change your database connection info to `mongo:27017` to work.